# Modify Default WebPart Page Template

Tags: web-part-page

I am having some trouble with the OOB WebPart Page in a SharePoint 2010 Team Site (that's right, I'm not allowed to turn on publishing framework)

1. The quicklaunch menu is hidden
2. The header does not inherit the logo or style from the master page

I can solve both of these problems by customizing the WebPart page in SP Designer, however.. I need these changes to take effect every time a WebPart page is created, as the end users creating the pages won't be savvy enough to do the customizations in SP Designer.

So I am wondering: **Is there a way to modify the out of the box WebPart page template?**

Once again, I can't turn on the publishing framework, so is there any way to do it without it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How was quick launch hidden? What changes to you make using SharePoint designer to reenable it? What changes to you make to the the page to enable master page changes?